# Excel IF Statement identify when cell has contents

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

How do I tell MS Excel to use the contents from one cell if data exists (this data can be positive negative or zero).  If the data does not exist in said cell, use contents from another cell?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. We are here to help you where you have gotten stuck. Since we are not here to do it for you, you will need to share what you tried so far. Please edit your question to add details of how your data is laid out, including the formula you have so far.

Comment: To get you headed in the right direction, look at the ISBLANK function, which you could use with IF.

Comment: Are you referencing the contents in the cell that you're modifying? If so, this would be VBA, not a formula.

Answer (score 1):

If there is anything in **A1** then use it, else use **B1**

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A1),B1,A1)
```